# converting nested FOR loops into stream using stream Java 1.8

Tags: java

Would like to know , how to convert two nested FOR loops using java 1.8 stream . 
Scenario:
variable usrAccountId - sent by User and 
variable accountDetailsinRedis- actually accounts presents in database. 
I am actually comparing accountId sent by user is same as accountId in the database. 
This is below code , I have two nested FOR loops ,  I want to convert it into Java 1.8 using Stream . Anyone has any idea.

```
for (int usrAccountId : acctIDstoValidate) {

        for (Account account : accountDetailsinRedis) {
```

Comment: I think it's not possible, because you're using it on the first loop

Comment: Can you share an [mcve]?

Comment: Are you trying to test if the IDstoValidaze do exist?

Comment: You may be able to use `flatMap`, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: I am trying to test user sent accountIds are actually present in the database or not , if they are present , Then I will check the authorityType . Below is my complete code which I partially converted in stream but not able to convert above FOR loops .   code -                                                                       IDstoValidaze

Comment: My guess is that you should then not loop, but instead execute a database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your actual logic, you pass multiple `id`s to match.
So you could have multiple matchings.

Stream on `acctIDstoValidate`, then chain it with a `flatMap()` on `accountDetailsinRedis` to do the filter on the `id`.

```
Collection<Integer> acctIDstoValidate = ...;
Collection<Account> accountDetailsinRedis = ...;


List<Account> matching = acctIDstoValidate.stream()
         .flatMap(idToValidate-> accountDetailsinRedis.stream()              
                           .filter(b-> b.getId() == idToValidate))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you to all of you very quick response

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more detail about what are you doing inside loop? 
For me, I don't what are you doing here, therefore that I just suggest You can use like this:

```
acctIDstoValidate.forEach(item -> {
   accountDetailsinRedis.forEach({
    //TODO
   })
});
```

some thing like below code snippet

Answer (score 0):

With a bot of guesswork, assuming both variables you have in your example are collections, this might be what you are after:

acctIDstoValidate.removeAll(
accountDetailsinRedis.stream()
   .map(Account::getId)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
)

And you end up with invlid ids left in: acctIDstoValidate

Also note that your variable naming xan be improved, to consistently use account instead of sometimes shortening it to acct, and not capitalizing ID for better camel casing: accountIdsToValidate